# Executing `android update project` fails in ANT, can't find sdkmanager.jar

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, ant

When trying to execute an android update on a project i am getting the following error. Using linux.

Here is the ant code (where `${directory}` is the directory of an android project):

```
<exec
    executable="/bin/bash"
    failonerror="true">
        <arg value="android"/>
        <arg value="update"/>
        <arg value="project"/>
        <arg value="-p"/>
        <arg value="${directory}"/>
</exec>
```

---

Here is the error:

```
[exec] android: can't find sdkmanager.jar
```

---

I have tried changing the permissions of `sdkmanager.jar` to `777` and it still gives the same error.

When executing the same command from a bash or shell script it works fine. And when running on the terminal it works fine.

What is causing this problem and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the script you are calling already contains the `!/bin/sh` at the top of the script you do not need to call the `/bin/bash` executable in the ant `exec`.

Therefore, if i change the code posted in the question to this...

```
<exec
    executable="android"
    failonerror="true">
        <arg value="update"/>
        <arg value="project"/>
        <arg value="-p"/>
        <arg value="${directory}"/>
</exec>
```

... it works fine.

Thanks, hope this helps someone in the future.